# Is there a tool to properly organize tag attributes for asp files?

Tags: asp.net

I realize that VS200X can ident asp files properly, however, for the sake of ease in finding attributes, is there a tool that will also organize the attribute order within a tag alphabetically? I'm always scanning around a tag visually and if the attributes were sorted alphabetically, asides maybe from ID and runat which should remain first, I would have a much easier time.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have never had so many attributes in a tag that it was a problem... are you perhaps trying to do style stuff in there instead of in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)**

You can set the set-attributes option in the config file to alpha, and all the attributes will be sorted alphabetically.

> Attribute: **sort-attributes**
>   Type: enum
>   Default: none
>   Example: none, **alpha**
>
> This option specifies that tidy should sort attributes
>   within an element using the specified sort algorithm.
>   If set to "alpha", the algorithm is an ascending alphabetic sort.

Example config file (tidy.config):

```
sort-attributes:alpha
show-body-only:yes
```

Example input file (test.html):

```
<a href="2" class="1"></a>
```

Executed command:

```
tidy -config tidy.config test.html
```

Results:

```
<a class="1" href="2"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this product, but Google turned up something called "Microsoft Expression Web".  (See here: http://www.expression-web.net/category/microsoft-expression-web/ )

The part that seems relevant to what you want to do is at the very bottom of the page:

> **Alphabetized HTML attributes**
>
> A new setting in the Code Formatting options in the Page Editor Options dialog box enables you to control whether HTML attributes are alphabetized or not in the code of your web pages. By default, tag attributes are now written in alphabetical order when Expression Web 2 adds HTML tags to your page. Existing tags in a page are affected by the new setting only if you apply the Reformat HTML command to the page.

Answer (score 0):

This answer needs updating as Expression Web 4 has been discontinued and is no longer being sold by Microsoft.

The best available utility for "beautifying" HTML code and for sorting HTML attributes within elements on an HTML 5 document seems to be here:
http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&l=html

My testing has show the above tool to offer superior HTML formatting features. Even Visual Studio 2015 does not have an out-of-the-box option to sort HTML attributes upon reformatting HTML code.

The cited utility above also is able to sort JSON object fields.