# How to order HTML attributes alphabetically on Visual Studio automatically?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, plugins, formatting, autoformatting

I have

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the attributes are unordered. I want a tool that orders the attributes in the HTML as the [XamlStyler](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/) does for XAML. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't do this AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think visual studio has this functionality. But if you use Resharper  just open the contextual menu and select reorder attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a context-menu option in ReSharper 8.x for doing what is mentioned above. However, my answer below might help others seeking an answer that seems to work quite nicely although the utility I cite currently is a hosted solution (it's free at the moment):
[Is there a tool to properly organize tag attributes for asp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030351/is-there-a-tool-to-properly-organize-tag-attributes-for-asp-files/31619454#31619454)